# He starts work every day at 9:00 am

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Is it correct to put clock information at the end of the sentence if there is another time adverb such as **in the mornings**, **every day** or **on weekdays** in the sentence?
Does it sound natural?

> He starts work every day at 9:00 am.

Comment: You could equally reverse the time and the day. Or, if you wanted to put the emphasis elsewhere, **Every day, at 9:00 a.m. he starts work - At 9:00 a.m. every day he starts work.** All are perfectly acceptable. The context might favour one or the other.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your version.  If you wanted to avoid "am" you could write, "He starts work every **morning** at 9:00."

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, does it work every time? For example : I wake up in the mornings at 8 .

Comment: it is quite common in ordinary text to write times that are exact hours as '9 am' rather than '9:00 am' with colon and zeroes for minutes. Many style guides specify a space before am or pm and some require capital letters, so all of these are possible 9AM, 9 AM, 9am, 9 am. If you use 24 hour time e.g. 09:00, 13:30, etc, you do not use am or pm.